# Refer to a variable in MAXIF

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

```
Sub test()
With Sheets("DATA")
    'test1 ---> cell A1 has a correct result
.Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(LEFT(C1:C10000,3) = ""PB-"",SUBSTITUTE(C1:C10000,""PB-"","""")+0))"

    'test2 has a correct result
test2 = .[max(if(left(c1:c10000,3)="PB-",substitute(c1:c10000, "PB-" ,"")+0))]

    'test3 gave me an error 2015 in locals window
test3 = Evaluate("max(if(left(c1:c10000,3)=""PB-"",substitute(c1:c10000, ""PB-"" ,"")+0))")
End With
End Sub
```

What I want :
C1:C10000 is a range coming from `set rg = .range("data").columns(2)`
"PB-" is a value coming from `id = .range("D1").value`
Not writing the result to a cell first.

So, before I implement the variable, I want to test it first by writing the code in test3 with `evaluate` syntax which almost the same like test1. But since the test3 already gave me an Error2015, I can't move on to try to change the code into some variables.

I've also tried `""""` for the "PB-" substitution in test3, but the result is 0.

My question:

1. How the code in test3 should be ?
2. How is the code in test3 (or maybe test2) if using the rg and id variable ?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

```
Sub test()
With Sheets("DATA")
Set rg = .Range("data").Columns(2)
'rg.Select
ID = "PB-"
test3a = rg.Parent.Evaluate("MAX(IF(LEFT(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ",3) = " & ID & ",SUBSTITUTE(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & "," & ID & ","""")+0))")
test3b = Evaluate("max(if(left(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ",3)=""" & ID & """,substitute(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ", """ & ID & """ ,"")+0))")
test3c = Evaluate("max(if(left(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ",3)=""" & ID & """,substitute(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ",""" & ID & ""","""")+0))")
End With
End Sub
```

Sub test3a and test3b give me Error2015, test3c give me 0 result.
The debug.print result of test3c is `max(if(left(C1:C12921,3)="PB-",substitute(C1:C12921,"PB-","")+0))`
`

Comment: `.Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(LEFT(" & rg.Address(0,0) & ",3) = " & id & ",SUBSTITUTE(" & rg.Address(0,0) & "," & id & ","""")+0))"`

Comment: @ScottCraner, thank you for your help. I'm very very sorry as I forget to explain in my question that what I want is the test2 or test3 which use rg and id. So, I don't need to write it first to a cell. I've edited my question.

Comment: That does not change the string part of the line.  just use: `test3 = rg.Parent.Evaluate("MAX(IF(LEFT(" & rg.Address(0,0) & ",3) = " & id & ",SUBSTITUTE(" & rg.Address(0,0) & "," & id & ","""")+0))")`

Comment: Hi FaneDuru and Scott, I'm very sorry, it still gave me Error 2015. I put a complete code with your suggestion in my question.

Comment: Please, try: `test3 = Evaluate("max(if(left(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ",3)=""" & id & """,substitute(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ", """ & id & """ ,"")+0))")`. Please, test this way. I made a stupid mistake when added `Evaluate`...

Comment: @FaneDuru, I'm sorry, it still gave me Error2015.

Comment: Please, try `Debug.Print "max(if(left(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ",3)=""" & id & """,substitute(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ", """ & id & """ ,"")+0))"`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`? It should return the formula as it should be in the cell.

Comment: @FaneDuru, `max(if(left(C1:C12921,3)="PB-",substitute(C1:C12921, "PB-" ,")+0))` ---> this is the result in immediate window for debug.print

Comment: There are two extra spaces and two double quotes missing. Please, try `Debug.Print "max(if(left(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ",3)=""" & id & """,substitute(" & rg.Address(0, 0) & ",""" & id & ""","""")+0))"`. Isn't it what you have in the cell formula?

Comment: @FaneDuru, this is the result of your 2nd debug.print `max(if(left(C1:C12921,3)="PB-",substitute(C1:C12921,"PB-","")+0))`

Comment: @FaneDuru, if you don't mind, how about my first question ? Using `evaluate` but direct range and value, So without the rg and id variable. My test3 in the original question, gave me error2015 if I use `""` for PB- substitution, and gave me 0 if use `""""` for PB- substitution.

Comment: @FaneDuru: The evaluation string in your last comment was correct.

Comment: @FaneDuru, thank you very much. Your code in `test3c =` now works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formula vs Shortcut Notation vs Evaluate

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestInitial()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
        
        Dim Test1
        .Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(LEFT(C1:C10,3)=""" _
            & "PB-"",SUBSTITUTE(C1:C10,""PB-"","""")+0))"
        Test1 = .Range("A1").Value
        Debug.Print "Initial Test1 = " & Test1
        
        Dim Test2
        Test2 = .[MAX(IF(LEFT(C1:C10,3)="PB-",SUBSTITUTE(C1:C10,"PB-","")+0))]
        Debug.Print "Initial Test2 = " & Test2

        Dim Test3
        Test3 = .Evaluate("MAX(IF(LEFT(C1:C10,3)=""PB-""," _
            & "SUBSTITUTE(C1:C10, ""PB-"" ,"""")+0))")
        Debug.Print "Initial Test3 = " & Test3
    
    End With

End Sub

Sub TestFinal()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
        
        Dim rgAddress As String
        rgAddress = .Range("data").Columns(2).Address(0, 0)
        ' To exclude the first cell (header), instead you could do:
        'With .Range("data").Columns(2)
        '    rgAddress = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Address(0, 0)
        'End With
        
        Dim ID As String: ID = CStr(.Range("D1").Value)
        
        Dim Test1
        .Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(LEFT(" & rgAddress & ",3)=""" _
            & ID & """,SUBSTITUTE(" & rgAddress & ",""" & ID & ""","""")+0))"
        Test1 = .Range("A1").Value
        Debug.Print "Final Test1 = " & Test1
        
        Dim Test2
        Test2 = .[MAX(IF(LEFT(data,3)=D1,SUBSTITUTE(data,D1,"")+0))]
        Debug.Print "Final Test2 = " & Test2

        Dim Test3
        Test3 = .Evaluate("MAX(IF(LEFT(" & rgAddress & ",3)=""" _
            & ID & """,SUBSTITUTE(" & rgAddress & ",""" & ID & ""","""")+0))")
        Debug.Print "Final Test3 = " & Test3
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, VBasic2008. It works like a charm.  (test2 throw me Error2015). I'm just curious why FaneDuru's code not working on my side. It looks almost the same like yours, the difference is just in your version the rg variable already included `.address`, while FaneDuru's version the `.address` is used in `test3 =` line.

Comment: In which version do you get an error, *Initial* or *Final*? Also, I wrote that FaneDuru's evaluation string was correct, but you need to use the dot to make it work correctly, whether the worksheet is active or not: `.Evaluate(...)`.

Comment: the "Error 2015" show by the time the yellow want to execute `test3 =`. Just now I tried your suggestion, using the dot `.Evaluate(` to FaneDuru's code. Yes, it gave me a correct result. Thank you very much, VBasic2008